# Simple: Subtracting two columns in Excel VBA and filling down to the end of sheet in specific column

Tags: excel, vba

This is quite simple, I am aware, but something is going wrong for me. I simply want to subtract the values I have in column B from the values I have in column C and place these results in column Q.

I have assigned my strFormula(1) as a variant and then applied the equation to the strFormula(1). I have altered the following code from @Manhattan here on Stack Overflow :)

```
Sub FormulasNoLoops()

    Dim strFormulas(1) As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        strFormulas(1) = "=(C2-B2)"
        .Range("Q2:Q130").Formula = strFormulas
        .Range("Q2:Q130").FillDown
   End With

End Sub
```

There is no error when I run the script but also no result in column Q. 
Ideally, I do not even want to enter the last cell of the column but maybe use `.End(xlUp)` somewhere.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first

```
Dim strFormulas(1) As Variant
```

is creating an array with two items, `0,1`

For one formula I would avoid the variable totally.

But if you want to use it just make it a string without the `(1)`

```
Dim strFormulas As String
```

Then load it:

```
strFormulas = "=(C2-B2)"
```

Also when you apply the formula to the whole range there is no need to fill down:

```
Sub FormulasNoLoops()

   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("Q2:Q130").Formula = "=(C2-B2)"
   End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    last_row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("C2:C" & last_row)
    rng.Formula = "=B2-A2"

End Sub
```